# chrome extension that determines php framework

Tags: google-chrome, php, google-chrome-extensions

Is there an extension for chrome that can display what php framework was utilized for a site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Web Technology notifier](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/fnpgnmindcbkjbpblcklealdhnogmlko)

> Web Technology Notifier displays the technology that is executed by the Web server of the current page through an icon. Many modules and CMS can be identified, such as Phusion Passenger for Ruby applications (as Ruby on Rails and Sinatra frameworks), PHP based applications (like Zend Server or iPyramid), Zope (Python powered), Microsoft ASP.NET, and more.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[Chrome Sniffer](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/homgcnaoacgigpkkljjjekpignblkeae)

> This extension will help web developer to inspect web framework / CMS and javascript library running on current browsing website. An icon will appear on address bar indicates the detected framework.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Wappalyzer. It is a chrome extension that uncovers the technologies used on websites. It detects content management systems, eCommerce platforms, web servers, JavaScript frameworks, analytics tools and many more.